# Problem using package 'algorithmic':: LaTeX-Result: 0 Error(s), 0 Warning(s), 0 Bad Box(es), 0 Page(s)

Tags: installing, miktex, algorithms, texniccenter

I am relatively new to LaTeX, and I am having problems with using the `algorithmic` package. Whenever I add the command,

```
\usepackage{algorithmic}
```

and try to build the document, the number pages created is 0 and there are 0 errors and warnings too. I don't know where I am wrong.

I am using MikTeX 2.9 and TeXnicCenter 1.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Probably the known problem that TeXniCCenter blocks the on-the-fly-installation. Install the package with the package manager. Or compile once with texworks or on the command line.

Comment: See also http://www.miktex.org/2.9/issues , section "TeXnicCenter compatibility"